# Output the contents of a file to the powershell host window

Tags: powershell

This seems like something that should be painfully obvious, but for whatever reason I can't figure it out. From within powershell, I'd like to be able to print the contents of a text file to the host window (or pipe it into another command). I'm looking for something like this:

```
PS C:\> {some command} README.TXT
These are the contents of the Readme.txt file!
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
get-content README.TXT
```

In short:

```
gc README.TXT
```

If you are used to `cat`, you can use that too, it is just an alias for the above in Powershell.

Comment: Or "type".  Get-Content, the command so nice they named it twice twice.

Answer (score 2):

It exists also :

```
${full path file}
```

Ex :

```
${c:\silogix\t.txt}
```

Answer (score 1):

try it:

get-content .\README.TXT